# Casting to generics

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to cast a `DbSet<BaseContact>` to `DbSet<TEntity>`. My problem is as you see below, I am trying to input a `Contact` and convert it to the `DbSet<BaseContact>`, but I can only return a `DbSet` of type `DbSet<TEntity>`. `BaseContact` is the super class of `Contact`.

How can I do this cast? Any suggestions?

```
//Input: Set<Contact> -> Output: DbSet<BaseContact>
public DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>()
    where TEntity : class, IObjectState
{
    Return DBSet<BaseContact> as DBSet<TEntity>;
}
```

PS: making it not generic is no option because I am running some other types through it. The above code is not the whole function afcourse.

This is the full function:

```
public DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>()
            where TEntity : class, IObjectState
{
    var propertyInfos = GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in propertyInfos)
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(FakeDbSet<TEntity>))
            return property.GetValue(this, null) as FakeDbSet<TEntity>;
    }

    var baseType = typeof(TEntity).BaseType;

    while( typeof(object) != baseType )
    {
        foreach(var property in propertyInfos)
        {
            if(property.PropertyType == typeof(FakeDbSet<>).MakeGenericType(baseType))
            {
                var baseTypeDbSet = property.GetValue(this, null);
                // you will need to convert FakeDbSet<TBaseType> to FakeDbSet<TEntity>
                var entityDbSet = Convert.ChangeType(baseTypeDbSet, typeof(FakeDbSet<>).MakeGenericType(baseType)) as FakeDbSet<TEntity>;
                return entityDbSet;
            }
        }
        baseType = baseType.BaseType;
    }

    throw new Exception("Type collection not found");
}
```

Comment: That's not how generics and inheritance works. A `DbSet<Contact>` and a `DbSet<BaseContact>` have *no* inheritance relationship, no matter what inheritance relationship `Contact` and `BaseContact` may have. This is more obvious when you consider what happens if you do get the cast to work and then you have code that expects to be able to put a `SomeOtherContactDerivedFromBaseContact` into the set when it's being treated as `DbSet<BaseContact>` - how does the code that's dealing with it as `DbSet<Contact>` work then?

Comment: Where is the type "DbSet<T>" declared? The .NET EF type named DbSet isn't generic. In any case, I don't think you're going to be able to do what you want. C# generics don't have the kind of variance you're looking for here. Just because class A inherits class B, that doesn't mean that generic type C<A> inherits generic type C<B>.

Comment: @PeterDuniho of course it is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460(v=vs.113).aspx - and yes *some* C# generics have exactly this kind of *variance* for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx - see [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Ghost Damien is right here - you will not get this working without getting down to the entities and casting them by yourself - and in no case will you be able to get a writeable DbSet of BaseContacts from a DbSet<Contact> - this might lead to you writing a "CompanyContact" into a "PersonContact" set or whatever - what you could get is `IEnumerable<BaseContact>` from a `DbSet<Contact>`

Comment: @CarstenKönig: you're right, MSDN search failed to turn up the generic version of DbSet for me. I stand by my comment that "C# generics don't have _the kind of variance you're looking for here_." Interface generics doesn't solve the OP's issue.

Comment: @PeterDuniho no it does not - but not because there is no such thing for generics (there is!) but because it's just not possible in this case (mostely because you can read and write to a DbSet and it must stay homogenous)

Comment: @CarstenKönig: suit yourself. I never said C# generics didn't support variance. Just not in the way that was desired by the OP (a different type system might allow variance on all generics, not just those specially declared...unsafe though that might be [I'm looking at you Java!]).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I added the fullcode of the function maybe there is something that make it possible. I also tried: Convert.ChangeType(baseTypeDbSet, typeof(FakeDbSet<>).MakeGenericType(baseType)) as FakeDbSet<TEntity>